# Strange behaviour in scipy.solve_ivp when using an implicit method

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I recently ran into a question about integration and encountered a strange bug. I attempt a very simple problem using `solve_ivp`:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np

def f(y, t):
    return y

y0 = [1,1,1,1]
method = 'RK23'
s = solve_ivp(f, (0,1), y0, method=method, t_eval=np.linspace(0,1))
```

And it works fine. When I change to `method='BDF'` or `method='Radau'` I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-222-f11c4406e92c>", line 10, in <module>
    s = solve_ivp(f, (0,1), y0, method=method, t_eval=np.linspace(0,1))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\ivp.py", line 455, in solve_ivp
    solver = method(fun, t0, y0, tf, vectorized=vectorized, **options)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\radau.py", line 299, in __init__
    self.jac, self.J = self._validate_jac(jac, jac_sparsity)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\radau.py", line 345, in _validate_jac
    J = jac_wrapped(t0, y0, self.f)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\radau.py", line 343, in jac_wrapped
    sparsity)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\common.py", line 307, in num_jac
    return _dense_num_jac(fun, t, y, f, h, factor, y_scale)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_ivp\common.py", line 318, in _dense_num_jac
    diff = f_new - f[:, None]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I also get an error with `method = 'LSODA'`, although different (i.e. all implicit integrators). I do not get an error with any of the explicit integrators.

I tried this in spyder with scipy version 1.0.0 and in google colab (scipy version 1.1.0), with the same results.

Is this a bug or am I missing some argument I need for implicit integrators??

Comment: `solve_ivp` expects the signature of `f` to be `f(t, y)`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thanks, I was sure I read it the other way (post it as an answer and I will accept it). Still, I don't understand why it doesn't raise a `ValueError` with any explicit integration method

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Radau and BDF methods do not handle single-valued RHS functions. Making the function `f` above output a 1-D list solves your issue. Additionally, as mentioned by Weckesser in the comments, `solve_ivp` expects the RHS to be `f(t, y)` and not `f(y, t)`.

Like this

```
def f(t, y):
    return [y]
```